# Limits of Absolute Values in Fraction

Tags: calculus, limits, absolute-value

I am new at here and am having a problem in using piecewise function to evaluate the absolute value in following limits calculation.

$\displaystyle \lim_{x→a^-} \frac{a}{|a-x|}$           (where $a \leq 0$)

For denominator $|y-x|$, I tried the piecewise function as below:

1) $-(a-x), x \geq 0$    (e.g. $-(-2-(-1))$)

2) $(a-x), x \leq 0$    (e.g.  $(-2-(-1))$)

But I feel that the piecewise results are wrong as $x$ can never be positive because of the condition that $(a \leq 0)$ and $(x \leq a)$. Do I wrongly use the piecewise function to resolve the formula?

Comment: For the limit when $x\to a^-$, $a-x$ is always positive, and so $|a-x| = a-x$.

Comment: The two cases of $|a-x|$ should be from comparing $a-x$ with $0$, not comparing $x$ with $0$.